# List filters are not sticky, and have no effect on the next pages

Tags: bug, mobile-web, unanswered-questions, question-lists

I was on Stack Overflow, browsing the questions to find one or two to answer, and I noticed there is a filter option of "[Unanswered Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered)"

It appears to filter questions by unanswered, but when I click on the next page it resets to the by votes filter, and the list is not filtered to unanswered questions.

I was using Google Chrome on Android, on an [ZTE Axon M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-touchscreen#Use_in_products).

Comment: Are you using the mobile or the responsive (full site) site design? You can check in the footer of the page.

Comment: I cannot reproduce (Chrome on Android): for me, the filter stays at "Unanswered" when I go to the next page. Just in case: note that "Unanswered" actually means "with no upvoted or accepted answers", so some questions with (<=0 score) answers also show up there.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm using the mobile version of the site

Comment: I figured as much @rexfordkelly, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce using the mobile site design. 
Using Chrome 84.0.4147.89 on Android 10 using Huawei P10-Pro

Using the full site does not reproduce this issue. To switch to using full-site scroll to the bottom of the page and select "full site" in the footer.

Comment: Ok cool, so that is a work around... Good to know.

Comment: It indeed is a work around, and probably this won't get a fix, unless it is something trivial, as SE is in the process of making all pages fully responsive and then discontinuing the mobile site. So if it needs a lot of work to get back in working order they probably won't invest in it. I'll leave it up to you if you want to accept my answer or not, I don't mind either way.